# Debugging Nodal with VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Good afternoon!

I am starting a project with the [Nodal.js](http://www.nodaljs.com/) framework and would like to take advantage of the Node debugging features in VS Code. I can't seem to figure out how to start the application using the debugger because the start command is 'nodal s' and I have tried following the instructions from this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) on attaching to process that is already running, but I can't seem to hit any of my break points. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!